# Is this function measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(B, \Sigma_B)$ and $(C, \Sigma_C)$ be standard Borel spaces and let $\mu$ be a sub-probability measure on $C$.

Given $Y\in \Sigma_{B\times C}$, I would like to use the following function:
$$
 f: B \to [0, 1] \\
b \mapsto \mu(\{c \in C \mid (b, c) \in Y\})  
$$

But I am stuck trying to prove that it is well-defined (i.e. the set in brackets is measurable) and measurable.

Comment: I suppose first you need to prove that $\Sigma_{B\times C}$ is the product sigma-algebra from $\Sigma_B$ and $\Sigma_C$.  (Maybe that is the defintion?  I don't know this notation.)  Then it follows from the definition of "product sigma-algebra" ... if $Y$ is one of the generators of the product sigma-agebra, then your set is well-defined; and the collection of $Y$ such that your set is well-defined is a sigma-algebra.  By the way: you also need to define "sub-probability measure".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a part of Fubini theorem for the characteristic function of $Y$.